# Where can I find logs of emails sent from an Exchange Relay

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

We've got a membership-based Web app that runs from an Internet-facing Windows 2003 server. That server is setup as a "relay" through our Exchange 2010 server. SOME, not all, users are reporting that emails sent from the web server aren't being received.

I'm wondering if there's a way to view logs of emails sent by the relay. I can't seem to find any utility in the Exchange Management Console; nor am I finding any email-related logs in the event viewer of the aforementioned web server.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find lots of logs at

```
\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\TransportRoles\Logs
```

"Protocol logs" sub directory has SMTP traffic which may help

Comment: Hey, thanks Phil... right on the money! In my case, the logs in the TransportRoles folder were empty but the MessageTracking folder had the info I was looking for. Thanks again!